# How do I interpret and plot the interaction from a glm in R?

Tags: normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, interaction, post-hoc, univariate

I am currently trying to analyze the duration of the egg stage of two species of insect (factor 1; 2 levels - HA and AP) at several different temperatures (factor 2: 5 levels - 20, 23, 26, 29, 32). After winsorizing my data to remove outliers my model is:

```r
model1 <- glm(winsorized.Duration ~ Temperature*Species,  
    family = "gaussian", data = egg.na.1)
```

Below is the summary output which shows that the interaction between the two factors is significant:

```r
Call:
glm(formula = winsorized.Duration ~ Temperature * Species, 
   family = "gaussian", 
    data = egg.na.1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-32.724   -9.874    1.776   10.046   25.708  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              104.869      2.104  49.845  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature23            -15.915      2.667  -5.968 3.92e-09 ***
Temperature26            -26.307      2.636  -9.982  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature29            -29.656      2.484 -11.940  < 2e-16 ***
Temperature32            -42.386      2.702 -15.688  < 2e-16 ***
SpeciesHA                -19.645      2.840  -6.917 1.09e-11 ***
Temperature23:SpeciesHA   15.566      3.737   4.166 3.52e-05 ***
Temperature26:SpeciesHA   14.695      3.455   4.253 2.42e-05 ***
Temperature29:SpeciesHA   12.744      3.401   3.747 0.000195 ***
Temperature32:SpeciesHA   19.310      3.829   5.043 5.93e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 163.7776)

    Null deviance: 181929  on 667  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 107766  on 658  degrees of freedom
AIC: 5313.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

I would like to look at how the effect of temperature differs between the two species so could anyone tell me which post-hoc tests I should use (and how to do them) and also how can I clearly plot this interaction? I apologize if the answers to these questions are obvious as I haven't used R for quite some time and am a little rusty. Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out R packages emmeans and sjPlot.

Comment: Create a plot, that often helps. Or otherwise, try to turn of and on your computer.

Comment: **1)** There's no real point in using `glm()` with `family = gaussian`, IMO, just use `lm()` for convenience.  **2)** That said, it seems like your outcome is a time until an event, so you should be using survival analysis, in that case.  **3)** Often, survival data look like they have 'outliers', but they aren't really, so again survival analysis may be appropriate, but windsorizing not.  **4)** You appear to have 4 temperatures modeled as unrelated factors; almost certainly `Temperature` should be modeled as a continuous variable, possibly with a squared term included.

Comment: `Species` seems to have just 2 levels.  So when the data are modeled correctly, tests and plots should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica In regards to the survival analysis does it matter that I do not have any censored data as I did not record duration for those individuals who did not reach the first instar stage.

Comment: Your dataset is biased, then.  Discarding the censored data and analyzing the rest is a classic red flag that's typically discussed on the first day of a course on survival analysis. If you can recover those data, you should.  Otherwise, if you know how many of each there were, you could try to simulate censored data as a sensitivity analysis.  Either way, this would need to be discussed as a limitation.  As for survival analysis, there is no problem with fitting a model without any censored data, assuming there actually weren't any.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I think I may be confused but isn't censored data usually for cases where the event would have happened had the experiment lasted longer? In my experiment some individuals died prior to reaching the next stage so they wouldn't have a duration value for the previous lifestage. Also, I have data on the numbers that did and did not reach each life stage so would you be able to tell me how I might complete a sensitivity analysis?

Comment: Those are censored data.  You have how long it took for some, and how long had elapsed when they died as censored data for others.  Regarding how to do a sensitivity analysis, you should ask a new question for that--it's too big for comments & doesn't belong in comments according to the SE scheme.