# How do I complete a sensitivity analysis to simulate censored data?

Tags: cox-model, bias, censoring, proportional-hazards, sensitivity-analysis

I am currently trying to analyze the duration of the egg stage of two species of insect (factor 1; 2 levels - HA and AP) at several different temperatures (factor 2: 5 levels - 20, 23, 26, 29, 32) using a cox proportional hazards model:

```
modelegg <- coxph(Surv(egg.na.1$Duration.egg) ~ 
              egg.na.1$Temperature*egg.na.1$Species + 
              egg.na.1$Date.eggs.added)
```

In a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/594140/28500) asked on this forum I was informed that in order to complete a survival analysis you needed censored data (in this case would be the egg stage durations of those who did not reach the egg stage e.g. time until death as opposed to time until reaching the 1st instar). Unfortunately I did not collect this information and so, as a result, it was suggested to me that I would need to complete a sensitivity analysis using data on the no's of died vs survived in order to simulate the censored data and reduce bias in my dataset.

I have never completed a sensitivity analysis so would anyone be able to tell me what a sensitivity analysis involves and how this could be done in R. Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Eggs that do not reach the first instar stage die, right?

Comment: @AdamO Yes that is correct. As a result I do not have duration values for them as I did not record the dates on which I removed the unhatched eggs. This is also the case for other life stage transitions e.g. 1st to 2nd instar where I did not record the dates of death.

Comment: That's unfortunate for a few reasons - statistically because this is not censoring either, censoring means the event can happen but you don't know when. If a sample dies, maturation can't happen - death is an absorbing state. Not even the Cox model handles this. You would need a competing risks model. You don't need to know the time of death, you can use time of most recently known alive, or the time known dead, but it can't all be time 0, and it can't all be end of experimental observation at, I dunno, 30 days.

Comment: @AdamO Is it possible to run a competing risks model without knowing time until death, as opposed to maturation, if you know the numbers reaching maturation vs. dying? Unfortunately, as I did not record the dates of death, I will not have data on time known last alive or dead. Also, as I am analyzing mortality at each life stage in separate analyses, I am only really interested in how long it takes to reach a particular life-stage if it is reached.